# Making squeaky stairs silent

Tags: stairs, noise

My stairs are creeky and squeaky. They are probably as old as the house (100+ years) so they are probably full of lose nails, but still i‘d like to remove as much sound as possible.

I took off the drywall and found that screws have been added to the risers and treads. And some blocks have been placed under the treads. My current thinking is that i need to glue and screw a 2x4 under each tread. Would bracing betweeen the stringers also help?

Any other tips or tricks?

[image: under tread]

[image: stairs]

[image: underside]

Comment: Squeak is spelled s-q-u-e-a-k.

Comment: Thought that didn’t look right! Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are gaps between the stair parts, pumping them full of polyurethane construction adhesive would help a lot.

If you add 2x4's under each tread, put them in with the 1.5" side horizontal and the 3.5" side vertical.

Comment: I saw a youtube video where they made a U-shape out of 2x6 for each tread, and then glued and screwed them in. Think the side parts are needed?

Comment: I went with gluing and screwing 2x6’s. I used PL Premium for ashesive, which i think is polyurethane. Anyways, it’s seriously strong. I’ve only done the first 4 steps and they are now silent.